# How to permanently remove "@public.talk.google.com" contact from Pidgin?

Tags: pidgin

Every day I remove a weird contact from Pidgin - the contact which looks like `12fgh4j84393j@public.talk.google.com` and the next day it appears. Even more, this belongs to a contact I removed months ago, but cannot remove this one.

What I tried but did not help:

- Unsubscribe
- Block
- Remove

Any suggestions?

Note. I use Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity (64bit version)

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't found out, its to do with people in your google+ circles.
Source:
http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/gmail/OhaG1DWHoXs/AqpOnnRj9ZMJ

Remove this person from your google+ circles, or follow the instructions on:
http://www.gaumire.com/2012/02/01/i-appear-publicly-on-google-talk-a-wtf/
or turn it off completely:
 http://possiblyuseless.wordpress.com/2014/02/07/how-to-get-rid-of-public-talk-google-com-contacts/

I know this is a little late, but thought it might be helpful to someone else.

Comment: Welcome to AU! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.